# MeanShift `fit` vs `fit_predict` scikitlearn

Tags: scikit-learn

Suppose `X` is an array of the typical form.  Given the code.

```py
from sklearn.cluster import MeanShift
ms = MeanShift(bin_seeding=True,cluster_all=False)
ms.fit(X)
```

Once I do this, `ms` has two attributes: `labels_` and `cluster_centers_`. *So my first question is.... what is the point of `ms.fit_predict(X)` or `ms.predict(X)` since we already have a classification of X which we can read from `labels_`?*

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is that when you say, `ms.fit(X)` , `X` is your labeled dataset/train dataset. on saying `ms.fit_predict(X')` , `X'` is your unlabeled/test dataset. ie, you are predicting on an unlabeled dataset with `fit_predict`.
i.e,  `fit(X)` performs clustering, while, `fit_predict`, gives you cluster labels. And there's nothing like, `ms.predict(X)`, on  `sklearn.cluster.mean_shift_.MeanShift` object. 
See also, `dir(ms)` for this, below.

```py
>>> help(ms.fit)
Help on method fit in module sklearn.cluster.mean_shift_:

fit(self, X) method of sklearn.cluster.mean_shift_.MeanShift instance
    Perform clustering.

    Parameters
    -----------
    X : array-like, shape=[n_samples, n_features]
        Samples to cluster.

>>> help(ms.fit_predict)
Help on method fit_predict in module sklearn.base:

fit_predict(self, X, y=None) method of sklearn.cluster.mean_shift_.MeanShift instance
    Performs clustering on X and returns cluster labels.

    Parameters
    ----------
    X : ndarray, shape (n_samples, n_features)
        Input data.

    Returns
    -------
    y : ndarray, shape (n_samples,)
        cluster labels


dir(ms)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_get_param_names', 'bandwidth', 'bin_seeding', 'cluster_all', 'fit', 'fit_predict', 'get_params', 'min_bin_freq', 'seeds', 'set_params']
```

With `ms` having attributes as `_labels` & `_cluster_centers`, with `X` data, you can then estimate the  goodness of the model using standard mis-classification penalty techniques. you can't estimate anymore with `fit_predict`, since you will get only labels, and not cluster centers. So, it is upto you to design the cluster centers, really, depending on your goodness criteria.

Comment: from sklearn.cluster import MeanShift
    ms = MeanShift()
    dir(ms)
Output:
['__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__doc__',
 '__format__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__module__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__weakref__',
 '_get_param_names',
 'bandwidth',
 'bin_seeding',
 'cluster_all',
 'fit',
 'fit_predict',
 'get_params',
 'min_bin_freq',
 'predict',
 'seeds',
 'set_params']

Comment: do you see 'predict' above? Are we importing the same modules? I am running scikit 15.2.  from sklearn.cluster import MeanShift

Comment: I'm on '0.14.1', but in any case, you could see what predict does using the same construct. Since I don't have it, I can't tell the difference.

Comment: Darn, well thanks anyway. I think it's interesting that I see `.labels_` and `.cluster_centers_` even after a `ms.fit()`, and so I don't see a reason for `ms.fit_predict()`. Go for the upgrade!

Comment: Hey just wanted to add, sometimes the latest upgrade might not be advisable, especially if you are using a lot of open source packages - since some of them may require upgrading the downstream packages. And, if they are beta/dev - all the best ! I( usually handle them via pip_requirements file - keeps things neat & re-producible across production machines.