# sklearn meanshift fit(X) then predict(Y)

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn

I am trying to use the 0.15.2 version of scikit-learn. In this version, the documentation shows that there is are separate `fit(X)` and a `predict(X)` functions as well as the combo `fit_predict(X)` function that was available in the prior version.

I thought that this would allow me to fit on one array and then predict on a new array (so `fit(X)` and `predict(Y)`). However, when I try this, I get a `ValueError` since the dimensions don't match.

Here is my code:

```
from sklearn.cluster import MeanShift, estimate_bandwidth
bandwidth = estimate_bandwidth(X, quantile=0.2, n_samples=5000)  # n_samples 100000 memory bound
ms = MeanShift(bandwidth=bandwidth)
ms.fit(X)
results = ms.predict(Y)
```

Is there a way to use the model to predict the clusters for a new (different) array than the array on which it was originally fitted?

I found this post ([MeanShift `fit` vs `fit_predict` scikitlearn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27162420/meanshift-fit-vs-fit-predict-scikitlearn)), but I think it was asking a different question than what I am trying to ask.

Comment: A little more info on the shape of X and Y and what you're trying to predict would be helpful. iirc X should be an m-by-n matrix (m features, n training vectors) while Y should be m-by-k (m features, k values. Might need k = 1)

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to reply. I can predict more than k = 1 (specifically when k = n), so I don't think that's the answer... I'll dig into the code a bit more to see if I can sort this out. I was just hoping someone would know off the bat. :)

Comment: Okay - I figured it out. It looks like m (the number of features) was my problem. I did the model fit using a subset of my features and then wanted the rest of the features for the next step so I tried to predict on the full data set, but of course, that's silly because how is the model to know which of the larger feature set was the original feature set? I guess I'll need to predict on the subset of features and then join back the other features I want to use for the subsequent step. Thanks for the m, n, and k discussion to help me think through this.